# Consulta sobre c# mvvm y patrones

Tags: c#, wpf, patrones-de-diseño

Hace rato que vengo mirando `c#`, `mvvm` y `wpf`, y cada vez que me meto más en el tema también me pierdo más. Aclaro que me encanta como funciona el `mvvm` y el tema de desacoplar las cosas.

He leído que se debe implementar (ej para una factura detalle), patrón `repository y unit of work`, también implementar `ioc` e inyección de dependencias, leo y miro vídeos en la red y mas o menos entiendo pero la mayoría de las explicaciones están por separados y en `mvc`. Entonces no logro saber como implementarlo en una aplicación realmente.

**Después veo en este [link](http://avanet.org/iniciando-con-entityframework-code-first/):**

- DbContext: Será el objeto que agrupará todos los elementos de nuestro modelo conceptual y manejará el mapeo de cada uno ellos con su par en la base de datos, incorpora el patrón unidad de trabajo y el patrón repositorio.
- DbSet: Comúnmente usado como tipo de propiedades al interior de una clase que hereda del tipo DbContext, este recibe un tipo genérico el cual representa una entidad de nuestro dominio, de esta forma habilita las operaciones CRUD para la entidad especificada.

Entonces digo: "no necesito crear el repository ni el unitofwork", ¿que hacer? y ¿cómo?.

¿Hay una explicación que reúna varias de estas cosas y se pueda ver alguna aplicación real o como lo implementan ustedes?.

La verdad que hace rato vengo queriendo realizar un programita `wpf` pero utilizando buenas practicas, pero no le encuentro la vuelta y me estoy cansando y pienso vale la pena.No sera mejor hacerlo como antes al estilo `visualfox` y `chauu`.

Gracias y Saludos.

Federico

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, deberías acotarla más a un problema específico. Échale una mirada a [como preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además etiquetaste para lenguaje C, cuando tu pregunta está relacionada con C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MVVM, es un patrón de diseño que va implementado en la capa de
>   presentación, se usa en WPF, en Windows Phone, etc.

Revisa este Link [WPF MVVM step by step (Basics to Advance Level)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

> IoC, es un patrón de diseño que reduce las dependencias codificadas
>   entre sus clases, eliminar esas dependencias permitirá que nuestro
>   código sea mucho más mantenible, extensible y testeable y permite
>   inyectar funcionalidades a las entidades de negocio.

Existen varios framework de IoC te puedo recomendar Ninject es el que habitualmente uso.

Revisa este link de como configurar Ninject en WPF [How to use Ninject in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615058/how-to-use-ninject-in-wpf-application)

**Federico: Entonces digo: "no necesito crear el repository ni el unitofwork", ¿que hacer? y ¿cómo?.**

> Si vas usar un ORM que te permite mapear nuestro modelo de datos a
>   nuestros objetos y estructura de clases de nuestra aplicación,
>   logrando con esto resolver el acceso y persistencia de datos sin mucho
>   esfuerzo y poder enfocarnos en lo que verdaderamente nos importa, el
>   dominio del negocio. En ese caso si te recomendaría implementar el
>   ***pattner Repository***, el ***pattner UnitOfWork*** sirve para abstraer la persistencia, todo depende de lo que desees hacer.

Comment: Hola Pedro Ávila, gracias por responder, la verdad necesito sacarme dudas porque sino dejo c#..jaja...porque tengo dos laburos diferentes y por ahi uno se siente que no avanza.

Veo y leo mvvm algo entiendo las cosas cuando las explican por separado. Pero por ej vi un patron repositorio y el unit of work que entendi ahora no se bien como aplicarlo estos dos en el viewmodel, implemento los command y demas en el VM pero si tengo el repository, el unitofwork como deberia ser mi VM.

Desde ya muchas gracias por responder Pedro y miro los link y aviso de lo que pude sacar en limpio.

Saludos

Comment: @Federico, debes ir aprendiendo paso a paso, todo de golpe te vas a marear. El pattner Repository lo implementarias en la capa de Acceso a Datos(Persistencia) siempre y cuando uses un ORM, sobre UnitOfWork no creo que lo necesites.

Comment: Hola @PedroÁvila gracias por seguir respondiendo.
Voy a implementar con code first y el repository(entre el finde y la semana que viena xq tengo que acomodar unas cosas en el local), despues me gustaria mostrarte el codigo a ver que te parece, no se si podre pasarte todo por aca, sino si me podrias pasar tu e-mail, y te envio el codigo.
Desde ya muchas gracias porque necesito poder sacarme algunas dudas ya que sino juntar las cosas, patrones e implementarlo en una aplicación se me esta haciendo imposible.
Saludos